# Accumulate if a cell contains specific text from a list

Tags: excel, vba

I want to accumulate a value in a cell every time the word "DELAYED" appears
(so I can check how many times it happened even if it was closed or scheduled afterwards).

[image: (this is what it looks like)]

I want it to happen automatically every time it changes.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If InStr(1, (Range("FX194:GK194").Value), "delayed") > 0 Then
    Range("GO194").Value = Range("GO194").Value + 1
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: All cells between "FX:GK" columns are list validated and you want adding all cases when "DELAYED" has been chosen on a row? Shouldn't it be as you show it in the picture? I mean "DELAYED"... Should there be cases to be counted as "He was delayed"?

Comment: I have seen things like that before. Next you will be asked the timestamp of the mentioned changes, and you'll be forced to opt for another solution: every time that value is changed, an entry is added in another worksheet, mentioning the timestamp and the word "DELAYED". In your sheet, the mentioned value will then just contain a `CountIf()` of the entries in that more detailed sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `target`- as this is the changed range.

Calling a sub that does the job you want and is named accordingly, improves readability of your code.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim c as Range

For each c in Target.cells  'in case multiple cells got changed
    If InStr(1, c.Value, "delayed") > 0 Then
        updateTotalDelayed c
    End If
Next

End Sub


Private Sub updateTotalDelayed(c as range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
With me.range("GO" & c.row) 'always use explicit referencing - in this case me represents the sheet where the event occured.
    .value = .value + 1
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next adapted event code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim LastR As Long
 LastR = Me.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

 If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("FX4:GK" & LastR)) Then 'the range in which the event will be triggered
    Application.EnableEvents = False
     Me.Range("GO" & Target.row).Value = Me.Range("GO" & Target.row).Value + 1
    Application.EnableEvents = False
 End If
End Sub
```

You do not need updating the cells which have not been changed...